# Jasmine ES6 exports

Tags: unit-testing, import, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to setup simple es6 project. I use Webstorm and in the file below I see `unresolved function or method` for `describe`, `it` and `expect`.

```
import Direction from "../source/direction";

describe('North', () => {
  it('has opposite South', () => {
    const opposite = Direction.N.opposite;
    expect(opposite).toBe(Direction.S);
  });

  it('has value of 1', () => {
    expect(Direction.N.value).toBe(0b0001);
  });
});
```

I can't find es6 exports for jasmine. I checked in `jasmine`, `jasmine-core` and `jasmine-es6`. **The tests themselves are running as expected.** I'm just wondering how to import jasmine methods into test files.

Comment: So your problem is Webstorm?

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to import mentioned methods because I can't find them in jasmine files.

Comment: What isn't working for you? You say the tests are running...

Comment: I want to write something like `import {describe, expect, it} from "jasmine"` but I can't.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the thing (purpose) you're trying to achieve, but can't?

Comment: I want to do that because I want to import methods I'm using. Not just silently accept that they are available at runtime.

Comment: You're not supposed to do that (proof being that it works as it is, and it's not documented otherwise).

Comment: Add Jasmine as a library in project settings. It doesn't make sense to import it just to satisfy Webstorm inspector, it is natural for these functions to be globals.

Comment: This problem also exists for webpack. It'd be nice to be able to import whatever is required to let webpack's dependency resolver do its thing.